# Should a comma, a semicolon, or a dash be used before 'trust me' at the end of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation

For formal writing, which one is technically correct?

1. I don't give a damn, trust me. (Is this a comma splice?)
2. I don't give a damn; trust me.
   (Should a semicolon be used?)
3. I don't give a damn — trust me.
   (Could a dash be used?)

Thank you.

Comment: Trust me: I don't give a damn.  (One could take that as (a) my interest in your question :-), not the case; or (b) a recommendation for a better way to construct the sentence, or (c) an attempt to introduce yet another punctuation mark :-)

Comment: As to #2. Why should I trust you just because you don't give a damn?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really think *any* version is appropriate in "formal writing" (unless it's reported speech).

The comma indicates a *stronger link* between the two statements, so we naturally interpret it as meaning *"You can trust me when I say that I don't give a damn"*.

Using a semicolon implies that the two statements are logically distinct, so we're more likely to assume the speaker means *"I don't give a damn [about whatever was just mentioned]. You can just trust whatever I say in this matter"*.

Both the above are just *tendencies*. It's still possible to adopt the "contrary" interpretation. But to my mind, the dash gives no real support to either alternative. So it's probably the worst option.

Comment: #2 has some really funny implications.  I can just imagine some politician:  I don't give a damn.  You should trust me!

Comment: @David: At the bottom of the [pork] barrel, I'm sure there are some US politicians who actually say *"I don't give a damn [about whatever it is they think their potential voters **also** don't care about]"*. But it's not a form of words I'd normally expect to hear from a British politician.